# specifying operand to dirname as a bash variable inside echo

Tags: bash, echo, dirname

Here is the one-liner I'm interested in (especially in the variable `out`):

```
find ~ | head -3 | while read f; do out=$(dirname ${f}); echo ${out}; done
```

I need to echo this one-liner before piping it into another program, but it fails:

```
echo "find ~ | head -3 | while read f; do out=$(dirname ${f}); echo ${out}; done"
```

with the following message:

```
dirname: missing operand
Try `dirname --help' for more information.
find ~ | head -3 | while read f; do out=; echo ; done
```

So I use single and double quotes:

```
echo "find ~ | head -3 | while read f; do out=$(dirname "'${f}'"); echo "'${out}'"; done"
```

which returns without error:

```
find ~ | head -3 | while read f; do out=.; echo ${out}; done
```

But `$(dirname ${f})` isn't echoed *as is*.

Any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to prevent substitution use single quotes or escape `$` :

```
echo 'find ~ | head -3 | while read f; do out=$(dirname ${f}); echo ${out}; done'

echo "find ~ | head -3 | while read f; do out=\$(dirname \${f}); echo \${out}; done"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a variable to store the command and echo the variable:

```
cmd='find ~ | head -3 | while read f; do out=$(dirname ${f}); echo ${out}; done'
echo $cmd
```

Comment: The variable isn't necessary, but if you are going to use it, you *must* quote the expansion.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why You need to print with `echo` only. But if you want in that way only then refer below:

```
echo `find ~ | head -3 | while read f; do out=$(dirname ${f}); echo ${out}; done`
```